# Find all the partial limits of $x_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\cdot\cos(\frac{2 \pi n}{3})$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is to find all the partial limits of $x_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\cdot\cos(\frac{2 \pi n}{3})$

I manage to find the partial limits of non-trigonometric sequences. But I’m not sure how to approach this question.

Comment: By partial limits due by chance mean partial sums?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(\frac{n-1}{n+1})$ converges to 1, so any subsequence do the same (converges to 1).
On the other hand, $(\frac{2 \pi n}{3})$ take only three values $(mod\ 2 \pi)$ and then $\cos(\frac{2 \pi n}{3})$ take three values only $\frac{-1}{2}$, $\frac{-1}{2}$, and $1$. So the product  $x_n$ has three related subsequences one which converges to $1*\frac{-1}{2}$, a second one which converges to  $1*\frac{-1}{2}$, and the third one to $1*1$. Any partiel limit is one of the mentionned three limits.